# BOM endian in C

Tags: c, file, endianness, utf-16

I understand that Big Endian and Little Endian can be encoded with a BOM that gives them away, but i'm so confused as for how i can evaluate this in C given a file.

```
00 00 FE FF -> UTF-32, big-endian
FF FE 00 00 -> UTF-32, little-endian
FE FF -> UTF-16, big-endian
FF FE -> UTF-16, little-endian
```

I have this piece of code to get the bytes from the file, but how do i know if it's little or big endian UTF-16 assuming the file starts with a BOM \xFF\xFE or \xFE\xFF.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
unsigned char c;

FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, f) == 1){
 fprintf(stdout, "%x\n", c);
}
}
```

And what would the file containing this BOM look like? (In either byte or regular text)?
I hope someone can help. Thanks.

I'm confused as for how to read the file and test if the first byte or bytes containing the BOM are little endian or big endian? How do i do that?

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing quite what you are asking.  I mean, you look at the first 2-4 bytes of the file, and check whether they match one of the BOMs you want to recognize.  If you can't figure out how to do that, then you'll need to be more specific about where you're having trouble.

Comment: @John s/having seeing/having trouble seeing/ ;). Also, OP, you might want to `return 0;` from `main()`, and also `sizeof (char)` is by definition `1`, so you don't need that there.

Comment: As for what a file "look[s] like", again, you'll have to be more specific.  You can't see the file itself with your eyes.  Are you talking about displaying its contents with some kind of tool?  About the representation presented by some particular file browser?  Something else?

Comment: And just another note, don't forget to check `argc` and make sure `argv[1]` is not `NULL` and contains the correct data; and check for `fread()` errors, etc. Also, so far, you haven't used anything that actually needs `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: I'm confused as for how to read the file and test if the first byte or bytes containing the BOM are little endian or big endian? How do i do that?

Comment: I would just read in 2 - 4 bytes, and either compare them with the various values for the BOM right away, or store them and then compare them later all at once; you probably want like a `switch` or a series of `else if`s or something.

Comment: @RastaJedi Can you show me?

Comment: Note that the options with zeros in them are for UTF-32LE and UTF-32BE, not UTF-16.  See the Unicode [FAQ — UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 and BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

Comment: Not sure how to implement..

Comment: Only interested in UTF-16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's a slicker way to do it than this, but it seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char c[4];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");  // b for Windows; a no-op on Unix

    if (f == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading\n",
                argv[0], argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t nbytes = fread(c, sizeof(char), sizeof(c), f);
    fclose(f);
    if (nbytes == 2)
    {
        /* UTF16 with BOM only? */
        if (c[0] == 0xFE && c[1] == 0xFF)
            printf("UTF-16BE\n");
        else if (c[0] == 0xFF && c[1] == 0xFE)
            printf("UTF-16LE\n");
        else
            printf("Two random (non-UTF) bytes 0x%.2X and 0x%.2X\n", c[0], c[1]);
    }
    else if (nbytes == 4)
    {
        if (memcmp(c, "\xFF\xFE\x00\x00", 4) == 0)
            printf("UTF-32LE\n");
        else if (memcmp(c, "\x00\x00\xFE\xFF", 4) == 0)
            printf("UTF-32BE\n");
        else if (memcmp(c, "\xFE\xFF", 2) == 0)
            printf("UTF-16BE\n");
        else if (memcmp(c, "\xFF\xFE", 2) == 0)
            printf("UTF-16LE\n");
        else
            printf("Four random (non-UTF) bytes 0x%.2X, 0x%.2X, 0x%.2X, 0x%.2X\n",
                   c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3]);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Odd-ball data size %zu (expected 2 or 3) - no diagnosis\n", argv[0], nbytes);

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I used a number of custom programs to create the data I tested it with, but the results were convincing enough to me:

```
$ cat chk.sh     
for file in utf-*
do
    ls -l $file
    odx $file | sed 2d
    printf 'File: %-12s - content: %s\n' $file $(utf61 $file)
done
$ sh chk.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 jleffler rd 4 Sep 19 15:01 utf-16BE
0x0000: FE FF 00 30                                       ...0
File: utf-16BE     - content: UTF-16BE
-rw-r--r-- 1 jleffler rd 2 Sep 19 15:01 utf-16BE.2
0x0000: FE FF                                             ..
File: utf-16BE.2   - content: UTF-16BE
-rw-r--r-- 1 jleffler rd 4 Sep 19 15:01 utf-16LE
0x0000: FF FE 30 00                                       ..0.
File: utf-16LE     - content: UTF-16LE
-rw-r--r-- 1 jleffler rd 2 Sep 19 15:01 utf-16LE.2
0x0000: FF FE                                             ..
File: utf-16LE.2   - content: UTF-16LE
-rw-r--r-- 1 jleffler rd 4 Sep 19 15:01 utf-32BE
0x0000: 00 00 FE FF                                       ....
File: utf-32BE     - content: UTF-32BE
-rw-r--r-- 1 jleffler rd 4 Sep 19 15:01 utf-32LE
0x0000: FF FE 00 00                                       ....
File: utf-32LE     - content: UTF-32LE
$
```

Comment: Thanks! It was something like this i was looking for, i was unsure as for how to do the comparison with the hexidecimals

Answer (score 3):

> C Reading file with BOM to test if UTF16 LE or BE

OP also seems to want to distinguish others too: UTF-32, BE and UTF-32 LE

Be sure to open the file in *binary* mode.  To open in *text* mode, the BOM may be consumed by the `fopen()` and not seen on subsequent read operations.

There are many BOM encodings to distinguish.  [This lists 10+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding).  As an example, let us work with: UTF32BE, UTF16LE, UTF8.  These can be determined by reading a few fixed number of characters or by reading 1-byte-at-time.  Hint: It is called a "byte" order mark.  Care is needed to cope with very short files.

Rather then put candidate BOMs in *code*, the following puts them in a *data structure* for clarity, ease of expansion and maintenance.

```
#define BOM_MAX_LEN 5

const char *BOM_Name(FILE *f) {
  static const struct BOM {
    char *name;
    size_t length;
    unsigned char signature[BOM_MAX_LEN];
  } BOM[] = {                                        // Various UTF encodings
      { "UTF8", 3, { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF } },           // UTF8
      { "UTF16LE", 2, { 0xFF, 0xFE } },              // UTF16LE
      { "UTF32BE", 4, { 0x00, 0x00, 0xFE, 0xFF } },  // UTF32BE
      // Add others as desired.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark
      { NULL, 0, { 0 } } };

  unsigned char BOM_Signature[BOM_MAX_LEN];
  rewind(f);  // Only file beginning
  size_t length = fread(BOM_Signature, 1, BOM_MAX_LEN, f);

  for (size_t i = 0; BOM[i].length; i++) {
    if (length >= BOM[i].length 
        && memcmp(BOM_Signature, BOM[i].signature, BOM[i].length) == 0) {
      fseek(f, BOM[i].length, SEEK_SET);  // Leave file position to just after BOM
      return BOM[i].name;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Note the non-uniqueness conflict mention by [@Todd Knarr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582332/bom-endian-in-c/39583759#comment66477760_39583759):  1) UTF16-LE BOM with following 16-bit 0 vs. 2) UTF32-LE BOM.  This method would accept whatever BOM encoding was tested first.  I would recommend listing UTF32-LE before UTF16-LE else it is never detected.  A robust solution would test deeper into the file to attempt a resolution.  (not shown in this answer)

Comment: It should be possible to clean things up a bit by using the first byte to determine a candidate encoding and then verifying the remainder of the BOM. Only two encodings have the same first byte, UTF-16 LE and UTF-32 LE, and there's an even nastier problem with those two: a UTF-16 LE file whose first character is U+0000 is indistinguishable from a UTF-32 LE file's complete BOM.

Comment: @Todd Knarr Good point about the UTF-16 LE and UTF-32 LE issue.  That issue, IMO, should be solved like the same if no BOM is found, by matching down up to a few kbyte, testing for candidate encodings.  The more  robust approach I have used assigned each candidate encoding a flag, that is turned off once when an encoding violation occurs.  Eventually only one flag remains (or a sane upper bound of file testing has occurred).  But that is more code than this example.  IAC, I prefer data driven testing rather than coding lots of `if`s.

Comment: And given that there's only one ambiguous case after the first byte's checked, testing until an encoding violation occurs seems a pretty reasonable approach for that case. For the rest I'd read the first byte which determines the only possibly-valid encoding, then compare the first few bytes of the file to the known BOM for that encoding to see if they match. If they don't, what you have's most likely a purely binary file rather than Unicode text.

Comment: Oops. Purely binary if the only alternative's Unicode text. The file might be ISO-8859-* or ASCII or some other text encoding that doesn't use the BOM, in which case things get really hairy. Try distinguishing the various ISO-8859-* character sets without knowing which one you're dealing with, for instance. Gah. And now I'm going to go bleach my brain after being reminded of that.

Comment: That's supposed to be `fseek(f, BOM[i].length, SEEK_SET)`, and `"UTF16LE", 2,{ 0xFF, 0xFE }`

Comment: @Todd Knarr  You hit upon an aspect of file encoding detection that makes it challenging because it lacks clear answer in pathological cases. In the case of multiple candidate answers, forming a list with the most popular (or only the most popular) may suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I was working on for you, sorry it took so long:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char bom[4];
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "rb");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
            perror("fopen()");
            return 1;       /* or EXIT_FAILURE, but would need <stdlib.h> */
    }

    if (fread(bom, 1, 4, fp) < 2 && feof(fp) || ferror(fp))
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred with fread() or file malformed.\n");
            return 1;
    }

    if (memcmp(bom, "\x00\x00\xFE\xFF", 4) == 0)
            printf("UTF-32, big-endian.\n");
    else if (memcmp(bom, "\xFF\xFE\x00\x00", 4) == 0)
            printf("UTF-32, little-endian.\n");
    else if (memcmp(bom, "\xFE\xFF", 2) == 0)
            printf("UTF-16, big-endian.\n");
    else if (memcmp(bom, "\xFF\xFE", 2) == 0)
            printf("UTF-16, little-endian.\n");
    else
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Malformed BOM.\n");
            return 1;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As per the other answer, I just changed `fopen()` to open the file in _binary_ mode; I'm not sure if it's necessary, but I would believe it if it is in some cases. I had forgotten about `memcmp()`; it might be better to use this over `strcmp()`, but that is why I used `strncmp()` with only _4_ for the size, so that it wouldn't be checking against the null byte at the end of the string literals.

Comment: It seems `strcmp()` should stop after reading the null byte, but for some reason it was working for me with the null byte embedded in the string literal, but I am going to change it anyways because I don't think it should have worked.

Comment: As [commented here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582332/c-reading-file-with-bom-to-test-if-utf16-le-or-be/39583759?noredirect=1#comment66477760_39583759), `memcmp(bom, "\xFF\xFE\x00\x00", 4)` and `memcmp(bom, "\xFF\xFE", 2)` both match a file that begins `\xFF\xFE\x00\x00`  UTF32LE and UTF16LE with the next Unicode character of 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, appreciated!